# Dequeue/deregister scripts for everybody but the administrator

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I'm trying to dequeue/deregister some scripts (the code is working) but I want them to be dequeued/deregistered for every visitors excepted the admin.

```
//Dequeue Styles
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles() {
    if(!current_user_can('administrator'))
    wp_dequeue_style( 'elementor-icons' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'elementor-icons' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'elementor-common' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'elementor-common' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles' );

//Dequeue JavaScripts
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
  if(!current_user_can('administrator'))
wp_dequeue_script( 'backbonne-marionnette' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'backbonne-marionnette' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'backbone-radio' );

}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts' );
```

I'm directly editing the functions.php and I've tried to do this with "if(!current_user_can('administrator'))" but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I usually use `current_user_can( 'update_core' )` to detect an administrator. Also, is `backbonne` a typo for `backbone`?

Comment: Oh, thanks! It worked with current_user_can( 'update_core' )! (For elementor plugin it's backbonne, I don't know why)